# How to use javascript to automatically grab the height of elements to change the CSS style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am a javascript beginner, I have a question to ask everyone!

Today I have a project, such as the CSS setting of the gray block demo in the screen using position: fixed; fixed in the screen!
There are three blocks at the top, namely a, b, and c, but sometimes the a block will display: none; that is, it will disappear.

But my gray block always needs to be fixed below the c blue block!

The way I thought of was to use javascript to capture the height of the three blocks a, b, and c, and then change the top value in the demo!
I wonder if this idea is feasible?

But I wrote an example the way I know, but why didn’t the effect come out?
Is my CSS syntax wrong?

Hope to get your help, thank you.

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.a').offsetHeight;
let b = document.querySelector('.b').offsetHeight;
let c = document.querySelector('.c').offsetHeight;
let demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
let all_height = a+b+c;


demo.style.top = all_height+"px";
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  height: 800px;
}
.wrap .a {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ffdd00;
}
.wrap .b {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fbb034;
}
.wrap .c {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00a4e4;
}
.wrap .demo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 210px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.wrap .select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="demo">Fixed block</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a diagram that you can use to help describe the behaviour that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/STKp17K is this desired result?

Comment: the effect looks like it came out fine to me, do you want the demo box to scroll along with the rest of the boxes? please elaborate what it is exactly that you want

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear!
In my project, the yellow blocks sometimes appear and sometimes they don’t. Therefore, I hope that when the yellow blocks disappear, the gray blocks can still be close to the bottom of the blue blocks, so I want to use js to judge the catch The total height of the top three blocks, and then dynamically change the value of top in the demo style, but my writing seems to be wrong, because it did not produce the effect I wanted, thank you everyone.

Comment: https://upload.cc/i1/2021/11/09/nTmuPB.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is I guess when you scroll down a fixed block to stand fixed at the top, I might be mistaken ..

First I want to mention that as a beginner it is good to follow good conventions. Use const instead of let, unless you re-assign value. Use CamelCase convention when declaring variables.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="demo">Fixed block</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  height: 800px;
}
.wrap .a {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ffdd00;
}
.wrap .b {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fbb034;
}
.wrap .c {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00a4e4;
}
.wrap .demo {
  display:block;
 width:100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.wrap .select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 260px;
}

.fixed-top{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
const a = document.querySelector('.a').offsetHeight;
const b = document.querySelector('.b').offsetHeight;
const c = document.querySelector('.c').offsetHeight;
const demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
const allHeight = a+b+c;


window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
          const position = window.pageYOffset;
           position> allHeight 
         ?  demo.classList.add('fixed-top')
         :  demo.classList.remove('fixed-top')
                  
});
```

link to jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/Markov88/34dawz9k/36/

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Here it is but you should make a js function that do a loop of elements with `.d` class and get the sum of their height. I will count automatically rather than a+b+c

> But my gray block always needs to be fixed below the c blue block!

This way you can show C block

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.a').offsetHeight;
let b = document.querySelector('.b').offsetHeight;
let c = document.querySelector('.c').offsetHeight;
let demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
let all_height = a+b+c;
 
demo.style.top = all_height+"px";
demo.innerText = all_height;
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  height: 800px;
}
.wrap .a {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ffdd00;
}
.wrap .b {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #fbb034;
}
.wrap .c {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #00a4e4;
}
.wrap .demo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.wrap .select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a d">A</div>
  <div class="b d">B</div>
  <div class="c d">C</div>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="demo">Fixed block</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
But it does not seem to be the effect I want to achieve. I hope that when the top yellow block displays:none;, the gray block can still be close to the bottom of the blue block.

Comment: check my updated answer